# how to cover the uncovered part in test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test

Recently i wrote a test class,but i got only 35%.how to improve code coverage for boolsave=true and pagemessages?can you anybody help me.[image]

**class:**

```
public class Rfleet_PaymentConditions {
public Boolean bool {get;set;}
/*public string callfunc{get;set;}*/
public Boolean boolsave {get;set;}
public Boolean showSave{get;set;}
public Boolean showSubmit{get;set;}
public Boolean showback{get;set;}
public string id;
public Account acc{get;set;}
public Boolean refreshPage {get; set;}
public Account getAccount() {
    return acc;
}

public Rfleet_PaymentConditions(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    bool = true;
    showSave = true;
    id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    acc=[SELECT Rfleet_UpperDate_Period1__c,Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period1__c,Rfleet_LowerDate_Period1__c,Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c,Rfleet_DueDate_Period1__c,Rfleet_DueMonth_Period1__c,Rfleet_UpperDate_Period2__c,Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period2__c,Rfleet_LowerDate_Period2__c,Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period2__c,Rfleet_DueDate_Period2__c,Rfleet_DueMonth_Period2__c,
    Rfleet_Depreciation_UpperDate_Period1__c,Rfleet_Depreciation_UpperMonth_Period1__c,Rfleet_Depreciation_LowerDate_Period1__c,Rfleet_Depreciation_LowerMonth_Period1__c,Rfleet_Depreciation_DueDate_Period1__c,Rfleet_Depreciation_DueMonth_Period1__c,Rfleet_Depreciation_UpperDate_Period2__c,Rfleet_Depreciation_UpperMonth_Period2__c,Rfleet_Depreciation_LowerDate_Period2__c,
    Rfleet_Depreciation_LowerMonth_Period2__c,Rfleet_Depreciation_DueDate_Period2__c,Rfleet_Depreciation_DueMonth_Period2__c,Event_Triggering_Billing__c,Rfleet_Billing_Type__c,Rfleet_Billing_Delay__c FROM Account where id=:id];

    }

public void ResetPayment(){
    acc.Rfleet_UpperDate_Period1__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period1__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_LowerDate_Period1__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_DueDate_Period1__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_DueMonth_Period1__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_UpperDate_Period2__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period2__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_LowerDate_Period2__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period2__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_DueDate_Period2__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_DueMonth_Period2__c='';
    acc.Event_Triggering_Billing__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_Billing_Type__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_Billing_Delay__c=0;
}

public void ResetDepreciationPayment(){
    acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_UpperDate_Period1__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_UpperMonth_Period1__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_LowerDate_Period1__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_LowerMonth_Period1__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_DueDate_Period1__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_DueMonth_Period1__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_UpperDate_Period2__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_UpperMonth_Period2__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_LowerDate_Period2__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_LowerMonth_Period2__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_DueDate_Period2__c='';
    acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_DueMonth_Period2__c='';
}
public void save(){

    bool =false;
    boolsave=false;
    showSave=false;
    showSubmit=true;
    showback=true;
}
public PageReference back(){
    refreshPage=true; 

    return null;
} 

public PageReference Submit() { 
    if((acc.Rfleet_UpperDate_Period1__c==Null ||acc.Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period1__c==Null||acc.Rfleet_LowerDate_Period1__c==Null||acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c==Null||acc.Rfleet_DueDate_Period1__c==Null||acc.Rfleet_DueMonth_Period1__c==Null||acc.Rfleet_UpperDate_Period2__c==Null||acc.Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period2__c==Null||acc.Rfleet_LowerDate_Period2__c==Null||acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period2__c==Null||acc.Rfleet_DueDate_Period2__c==Null||acc.Rfleet_DueMonth_Period2__c==Null)||(acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_UpperDate_Period1__c==null ||acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_UpperMonth_Period1__c==null ||acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_LowerDate_Period1__c==null ||acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_LowerMonth_Period1__c==null ||acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_DueDate_Period1__c==null ||acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_DueMonth_Period1__c==null ||acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_UpperDate_Period2__c==null ||acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_UpperMonth_Period2__c==null ||acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_LowerDate_Period2__c==null ||acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_LowerMonth_Period2__c==null ||acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_DueDate_Period2__c==null ||acc.Rfleet_Depreciation_DueMonth_Period2__c==null)){ 
       boolsave=true; 
        Apexpages.addmessage(new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning,'please must fill all Terms of Payment fields!'));
      }else{    
        update acc;
        Apexpages.addmessage(new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'Record saved Successfully!'));
       refreshPage=true;
    }


  return null;

 }

 //period1 LowerDate validation 
public PageReference Period1LowerDateValidation(){

       if(acc.Rfleet_LowerDate_Period1__c!=Null && acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c != Null && acc.Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period1__c!=null && acc.Rfleet_UpperDate_Period1__c !=null ){
         boolsave=false;
          if((Integer.valueof(acc.Rfleet_LowerDate_Period1__c)> Integer.valueof(acc.Rfleet_UpperDate_Period1__c)) && (acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c==acc.Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period1__c)){
                boolsave=true;             
                ApexPages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning,'Please select the past Date of lowerdate in Period1!!');
                ApexPages.addmessage(msg);

          }else if((Integer.valueof(acc.Rfleet_LowerDate_Period1__c)== Integer.valueof(acc.Rfleet_UpperDate_Period1__c)) && (acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c==acc.Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period1__c)){
                boolsave=true;
                ApexPages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning,'Should not same lowerdate/UpperDate in Period1!!');
                ApexPages.addmessage(msg);

          }else if((acc.Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period1__c=='M') &&(acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M + 1'||acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M + 2'|| acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M + 3')){
          // }else if((acc.Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period1__c=='M') && (acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c.contains('M + 1,M + 2,M + 3'))){
                boolsave=true;
                ApexPages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning,'Please select the past month LowerDate in Period1!!');
                ApexPages.addmessage(msg);

          }else if((acc.Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period1__c=='M + 1') &&(acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M + 2'|| acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M + 3')){
                boolsave=true;
                ApexPages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning,'Please select the past month LowerDate in Period1!!');
                ApexPages.addmessage(msg);

          }else if(acc.Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period1__c=='M + 2' && acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M + 3'){
                boolsave=true;
                ApexPages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning,'Please select the past month LowerDate in Period1!!');
                ApexPages.addmessage(msg);

          }else if((acc.Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period1__c=='M - 1') &&(acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M'|| acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M + 1'|| acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M + 2'|| acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M + 3')){
                boolsave=true;
                ApexPages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning,'Please select the past month LowerDate in Period1!!');
                ApexPages.addmessage(msg);

          }else if((acc.Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period1__c=='M - 2') &&(acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M - 1'|| acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M'|| acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M + 1'|| acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M + 2'|| acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M + 3')){
               boolsave=true;
                ApexPages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning,'Please select the past month LowerDate in Period1!!');
                ApexPages.addmessage(msg);

          }else if((acc.Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period1__c=='M - 3') &&(acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M - 1'|| acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M - 2'|| acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M'|| acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M + 1'|| acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M + 2'|| acc.Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c=='M + 3')){
               boolsave=true;
                ApexPages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Warning,'Please select the past month LowerDate in Period1!!');
                ApexPages.addmessage(msg);

          }

    }
   return null;
}
```

**test class:**

```
@isTest
public class Rfleet_PaymentConditions_Test {
   static testMethod void testpayment(){

        Account acct = new Account(Name='john',Montant__c=5);
        insert acct;
        acct.Name='joshua';
        update acct;
        Account paytest = [Select id,Name,Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period1__c from account LIMIT 100];
        pagereference vfpage = page.RFLEET_PaymetCondition;
        system.Test.setCurrentPage(vfpage);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', paytest.id);
        apexpages.StandardController sc = new apexpages.StandardController(paytest);
        Rfleet_PaymentConditions pay = new Rfleet_PaymentConditions(sc);
        pay.save();
        pay.back();
        pay.getAccount();
        pay.boolsave=false;
        pay.Submit();
        pay.Period1UpperDateValidation();
        pay.Period2LowerDateValidation();

        }
    static testMethod void testpayment1(){
        Account acct = new Account(Name='john',Montant__c=5,Rfleet_UpperDate_Period1__c='21',Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period1__c='M + 1',Rfleet_LowerDate_Period1__c='21',
                                    Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period1__c='M - 1',Rfleet_DueDate_Period1__c='21',Rfleet_DueMonth_Period1__c='M + 2',Rfleet_UpperDate_Period2__c='21',
                                    Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period2__c='M + 3',Rfleet_LowerDate_Period2__c='21',Rfleet_LowerMonth_Period2__c='M - 2',Rfleet_DueDate_Period2__c='21',
                                    Rfleet_DueMonth_Period2__c='M + 3',Rfleet_Depreciation_UpperDate_Period1__c='21',Rfleet_Depreciation_UpperMonth_Period1__c='M + 1',
                                    Rfleet_Depreciation_LowerDate_Period1__c='21',Rfleet_Depreciation_LowerMonth_Period1__c='M - 3',
                                    Rfleet_Depreciation_DueDate_Period1__c='21',Rfleet_Depreciation_DueMonth_Period1__c='M + 2',Rfleet_Depreciation_UpperDate_Period2__c='21',
                                    Rfleet_Depreciation_UpperMonth_Period2__c='M + 1',Rfleet_Depreciation_LowerDate_Period2__c='21',
                                    Rfleet_Depreciation_LowerMonth_Period2__c='M - 3',Rfleet_Depreciation_DueDate_Period2__c='21',Rfleet_Depreciation_DueMonth_Period2__c='M + 3');
        insert acct; 
        acct.Name='joshua1';
        acct.Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period1__c='4';
        update acct;
        Account paytest = [Select id,Name,Rfleet_UpperMonth_Period1__c from account LIMIT 1];
        pagereference vfpage = page.RFLEET_PaymetCondition;
        system.Test.setCurrentPage(vfpage);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', paytest.id);
        apexpages.StandardController sc = new apexpages.StandardController(paytest);
        Rfleet_PaymentConditions pay = new Rfleet_PaymentConditions(sc);
        pay.Submit();
        pay.save();
        pay.getAccount();
        pay.Period1LowerDateValidation();
        pay.Period1UpperDateValidation();
        pay.Period1DueDateValidation();
        pay.Period2LowerDateValidation();
        pay.Period2UpperdateValidation();
        pay.Period2DuedateValidation();
        pay.DepreciationPeriod1LowerDateValidation();
        pay.DepreciationPeriod1UpperDateValidation();
        pay.DepreciationPeriod1DueDateValidation();
        pay.DepreciationPeriod2UpperDateValidation();
        pay.DepreciationPeriod2LowerDateValidation();
        pay.DepreciationPeriod2DueDateValidation();
        pay.ResetPayment();
        pay.ResetDepreciationPayment();
        pay.back();
        pay.boolsave=true;



 }
}
```

Comment: Set up your data to meet the requirements in the class. Use multiple test methods to cover all possibilities. Right now it is basically saying that your test data does not meet the conditions so you will have to review things to understand why and mock your data correctly

Comment: hello eric i have added all the methods and requirements.but boolsave=true is only problem.can you help me

Comment: Boolsave=true is not your only problem according to the image you posted...

Answer (score 3):

You need to write 3 additional test methods. One with data that satisfies each of the `if - else if` statements that you're not meeting in your uncovered test code lines.